# force login password prompt in Debian 8 single user mode

Tags: linux, debian

If I would like to force a login password prompt in single user mode of a Debian 7 machine, I add the following to /etc/inittab using a script each time I would like to harden the system.

```
~~:S:wait:/sbin/sulogin
```

However this not the case in Debian 8, I can see that in Debian 8 /etc/inittab is missing and it has been replaced by systemd, so what I have to do to achieve the same in Debian 8 machine?

Comment: I have tried adding the same line to my /etc/initab file to password protect  single user mode. but it is still entering the single user mode without password. I am using Wind River Linux. Do you have any idea about that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default when booting Debian 8 (Jessie) in single user mode is already to ask for the root password.